# Exercise Equipment for Patellar Sublaxation

Tags: strength-training, knees

I've been prone to patellar sublaxation since I was a small kid.

Have been doing PT exercises every day at home, not a single incident of patella coming out. I also do recumbent station bike 30 minutes daily, and walk nearly 11,000 steps.

However, for past year, I feel right knee is prone to patellar sublaxation, but luckily it never comes out.

Short of going to doctor (who will simply send me to therapy), what exercise equipment should I look for (especially with the upcoming black fridays, cyber mondays, etc)

Thanks